# acceleration measurement error

Tags: imu, calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I have an IMU.
Even if I have made the calibration of the accelerometer, it still gives me the wrong distance value of the robot when I integrate the acceleration twice.
And after the movement(when I stopped the robot), the acceleration is always different from zero.
How can I fix these problems?

Thanks for your helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11609/acceleration-measurement-error/) by [fresh_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/1129/fresh_ros_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Double integrating over the acceleration measurements is typically so noisy that the data can't even be reliable enough to use. I would recommend that you find another method to calculate distance because it will be incredibly difficult to get any reasonable data from your calculations.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could start by high-pass filtering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) your acceleration signal to get rid of the zero-offset. If your robot isn't moving but you still have an acceleration signal that is definitely going to be an issue when you integrate.

But likie Dimitri said - integrating an accelerometer really isn't a good way to track distance anyways.

---

Originally posted by [JoeRomano](https://answers.ros.org/users/34/joeromano/) with karma: 126 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1